# How to use the 14px Gohu font in URXVT?

Tags: fonts, rxvt

I want to use the 14 px from the Gohu Font [here](http://font.gohu.org/).

I installed the font

```
 $fc-list |grep -i "Gohu"
/usr/share/fonts/misc/gohufont-uni-14.pcf.gz: Gohu GohuFont:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/gohufont-11.pcf.gz: Gohu GohuFont:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/gohufont-uni-11.pcf.gz: Gohu GohuFont:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/gohufont-14.pcf.gz: Gohu GohuFont:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/gohufont-uni-14b.pcf.gz: Gohu GohuFont:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/gohufont-14b.pcf.gz: Gohu GohuFont:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/gohufont-uni-11b.pcf.gz: Gohu GohuFont:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/gohufont-11b.pcf.gz: Gohu GohuFont:style=Bold
```

and added this the the `.Xresources`

```
$ sudo grep  "Go"  .Xresources
URxvt*font: xft:Gohu GohuFont:style=Regular:pixelsize=14
```

I expected that the size to be 14px but it is just 11px

Answer (score 0):

Use directly the font:

```
URxvt*font: -gohu-gohufont-bold-r-normal--14-100-100-100-c-80-iso10646-1
```